# Angular Material Data Table without pagination is loading very slowly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been working in Angular as a new comer. There are tables in the database and I am retrieving in the API side. The client side developed with Angular is calling the API and showing the data in table. The table is material table and no pagination is implemented. Just a simple scrollable table. The issue is, when the amount of data is huge, e.g. 1600 rows, the table is loading very very slowly. Even the scrolling is also getting stuck sometimes. Any expert suggestion would be appreciated in this regard.

Here is my html code snippet:

```html
<div class="section">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=download() *ngIf="exportButtonVisibility" >Export Data</button>
        <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
          <div class="spinner-container">
            <mat-spinner id="spinner" *ngIf="spinnerVisibility"></mat-spinner>
          </div>
          <table mat-table id="excel-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead> 
              <tr mat-header-row >
                <th *ngFor="let head of rawDatas[0] | keys" >{{head}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody striped="true">
              <tr mat-row *ngFor="let item of rawDatas">
                  <td  *ngFor="let data of item | keys ;">{{item[data]}}</td>
              </tr>
              
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the typescript code:

```js
getDataInfo(value: any) {
    //debugger;
    this.loading = true;
    //let spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
    this.spinnerVisibility = true;
    this.exportButtonVisibility = false;
    this.rawDataHeaders= empty;
    this.rawDatas =[];
    console.log('schema', this.schema);
    //console.log("server address", localStorage.getItem("serverAddress"));
    let dbName = localStorage.getItem("selecltedDb");
    //localStorage.setItem('tableName',value.schema_name);
    let tableName =localStorage.getItem("tableName");
    console.log(tableName);
    let dbServerAddress = localStorage.getItem("serverAddress");
    let dbServerPort = localStorage.getItem("serverPort");
    let dbLoginId = localStorage.getItem("databaseLoginId");
    let dbLoginPassword = localStorage.getItem("dbpassword");
    this.dashboardService.GetTableData(dbName, tableName, dbServerAddress, dbServerPort, dbLoginId, dbLoginPassword)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        //console.log("server address", value.serverAddress); 
        this.loading=false;
        this.exportButtonVisibility=true;
        if (data != null) {
          localStorage.setItem('selecltedTbl', value.schema_name);
          this.rawDatas = data;
          this.rawDataHeaders = Object.keys(data[0]);
        }
        this.spinnerVisibility = false;
      },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );

      
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your kind assistance in this regard.

Comment: For me, the material table started showing issues when the number of rows where around 500 rows. Can suggest few things though: you can use `trackBy` and virtual scrolling for rendering the long rows of the table. Virtual scrolling is directly supported in the table have a look at https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10122#issuecomment-435041443 for more information on how you can update the table related code to achieve virtual scrolling

Comment: I have tried virtual scrolling....But it did not improve the situation that much...I am going to try again using the example and informing you the status

Comment: I've often seen this issue. Loading that much data is relatively quick; however, rendering that much data on a web page is expensive in terms of performance. You should look for ways to reduce the amount of data the browser has to render. One solution is virtual scrolling (as @Sumit suggested), showing only 20-50 results at a time. Another solution is pagination similarly showing a limited number of results.

Other potential causes include request latency from an API on a remote server, the API is fetching data from a database on a remote server, or slow data processing in the API.